# How to get value from the output of a weighing scale

Tags: python, serial-port, scale

I am trying to get the value of weight from the output of a weighing machine. I have connected the weighing machine with the windows PC using the RS232 to USB convertor. I am using python to connect and fetch the data. Following is the code used to fetch.

```
import time
import serial
import Tkinter
import re

window = Tkinter.Tk()
 
def PrintWeight():
    ser = serial.Serial(
        port='COM6',
        baudrate=2400,
        timeout=None,
        parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN,
        stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
        bytesize=serial.SEVENBITS
    )
    ser.isOpen()
    while 1 :
            bytesToRead = ser.inWaiting()
            data = ser.read(bytesToRead)
            time.sleep(1)
            print(str(data))

MyTitle = Tkinter.Label(window, text="Weight Display",font="TimesRoman 16")
MyTitle.pack()

MyButton = Tkinter.Button(window, text="FETCH", command=PrintWeight)
MyButton.pack()
 
dice_thrown = Tkinter.Label(window, font="Helvetica 16 bold")
dice_thrown.pack()
 
window.mainloop()
```

I am getting the output as -
[image]

As you can see in the image attached , 000050 within the square brackets is the value of weight , i.e 50 grms. How can I get only the numeric data out of this long series of data, i.e only *50*.

Even I used the following code to extract the numeric data from the string -

```
s = str(data)
m = re.search(r"\[([A-Za-z0-9_]+)\]", s)
print m.group(1)
```

But this is giving error --
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`

Please help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you paste here the value of `s` after doing `s = str(data)`?

Comment: The error means that the data doesn't match the pattern. `re.search()` returns `None` when it can't find a match.

Comment: I get the same output as I have attached the image above - 
[000050][000050][000050][0000][000050][000050][00050][00050][000050-[000050][*][0

Comment: Some of your data has non-numeric characters in the brackets. If you read a block of data where all the brackets are like that, you'll get this error.

Comment: @barmar How can be there no match when I am getting [000050][000050][000050][0000][000050][000050][00050][00050][000050-[000050][*][0

Comment: @Barmar, so how can I solve this, because all these data are coming directly from the weighing machine.

Comment: Check if the search succeeded before trying to use the match. `if m: print(m.group(1))`

Comment: By copying your sample output and trying the exact same code, I did get many matches. Could it be an encoding error? In that case you could maybe try: `str(data).encode(encoding='UTF-8',errors='strict')`

Comment: Also I wonder why you're allowing letters and underscore in your match if you just want the weights.

Comment: @Charbelabidaher Digits don't require any special encoding. All the standard encodings have ASCII as a subset.

Comment: @Barmar I tried to change the regex only for numerics, in that case also I am getting `None`. is there any other way to get the numbers only ?

Comment: Obviously making the regexp more restrictive won't make it match more things.

Comment: Instead of heuristically guessing from the received string to get the data, build the program logic based on the format described in the device specification document.

Answer (score 0):

you can put "baudrate=9600" instead of "baudrate=2400"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).